# Android camera information

Tags: android, android-camera

Is there a way to information on the camera buit into the phone?

Things like...

- if there is a camera!
- resolution
- if a flash is present

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using the Android SDK i'm not seeing any EXIF in my JPEG's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323722/using-the-android-sdk-im-not-seeing-any-exif-in-my-jpegs)

Comment: O I see what you are saying. Thats not quite what I was looking for. I was just writing a simple app that polls the phones basic information. Sensors screen size and screen density os version brand name model etc...   I figure that knowing a phones pixel resolution and possible settings is important to know to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at: [Camera.Parameters class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html)